# Configuring Node.JS container in Rancher

Tags: node.js, docker, rancher

I am attempting to deploy my first workload with rancher.

I am trying to edit the existing default rancher workload, after getting the rancher hello world example working.

I changed the docker image to node:10 and the port to 8080. I am not sure if I am able to do this directly from rancher, or if I need to create a docker image with my user in docker hub to do this.

I would like to have a generic image, and then add some additional configuration to rancher, so I can reuse these settings for other node.js projects.

I would like a base node.js container, and then add a parameter to checkout a specific branch of a specific project whenever the container boots for example. I am planning on getting this integrated with teamcity to deploy to the rancher containers whenever teamcity detects a new commit.

Doing this in stages, I would like to get a node:10 container within rancher up and running. Can this be done by simply adding node:10 as the image and setting the default port in the add port section? If so, what is the default port to use?

I have tried the above and I haven't been able to get the container to load, I get a connection refused when I try to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have different images. There are many projects which use this pattern.
For example you can check this repo: https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker

r-devel image is based on r-base image

https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/master/r-devel/Dockerfile#L4

This functionality is not specific to Rancher. After you have your containers packaged according to your needs, you can use Rancher to run them.